# Passing property trough route checker

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Im trying to pass my properties to a Crime module.

Usually i have something like this:

```
<Route path="/crime" time={this.state.time} element={<Crime time={this.state.time} totime={this.state.timers.crime} loadtimers={this.loadTimers} />} />
```

But in the code above im not using my privateJailRoute.

but using my PrivateJailRoute, im trying to pass my props. like this:

```
   <PrivateJailRoute
          isAuth={true}
          path="/crime"
          element={<Crime time={this.state.time} totime={this.state.timers.crime} loadtimers={this.loadTimers}/>}
          redirectTo="/jail"
       />
```

With that piece of code, i get the following error:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `Protected`.
```

this works, but wont pass anything:

```
<PrivateJailRoute
      isAuth={true}
  path="/crime"

  element={Crime}
  redirectTo="/jail"
   />
```

**Q: How can i send my time, totime and loadtimers properties within my JailRoute?**

JailRoute:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

let useAuth = () => {
  let [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);
  let [isAuth, setIsAuth] = React.useState(false);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:3000/onlinestate`, {
        withCredentials: true
      })
      .then((res) => {
          res = res.data;
        if (res.online && !res.jail) {
          setIsAuth(true);
        } else {
          setIsAuth(false);
        }
      })
      .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
  });
  return [isAuth, isLoading];
};

const Protected = ({ Component, redirectTo, path, ...props }) => {
  let [isAuth, isLoading] = useAuth();
  if (isLoading) return <div>loading</div>;
  if (!isAuth) return <Navigate to="/jail" />;
  return <Component {...props} />;
};

export const PrivateJailRoute = ({ element, redirectTo, path, match, ...rest }) => {
  return <Route path={path} element={<Protected Component={element} />} />;
};

export default PrivateJailRoute;
```

**Important EDIT:**

this works , but i get client sided error.

private changed:

```
export const PrivateJailRoute = ({ element, redirectTo, path, match, ...rest }) => {
  return <Route path={path} element={<Protected {...rest} Component={element} />} />;
```

calling as:

```
<PrivateJailRoute
          isAuth={true}
          path="/crime"
          element={Crime}
          time={this.state.time}
         totime={this.state.blabla}
          redirectTo="/jail"
       />
```

But this client side error:

```
 index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted 

component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. 

To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
        in Protected (at PrivateJailRoute.js:35)
```

*35:*

```
return <Route path={path} element={<Protected  {...rest} Component={element} />} />;
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to change

```
<PrivateJailRoute
      isAuth={true}
      path="/crime"
      element={<Crime time={this.state.time} totime={this.state.timers.crime} loadtimers={this.loadTimers}/>}
      redirectTo="/jail"
   />
```

in

```
<PrivateJailRoute
      isAuth={true}
      path="/crime"
      component={() => <Crime time={this.state.time} totime={this.state.timers.crime} loadtimers={this.loadTimers}/>}
      redirectTo="/jail"
   />
```

Answer (score 0):

### Edit: Slightly changed my answer for [react-router v6](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v6-pre)

There is a confusion in your code between "elements" and "components". A component is basically a type whereas an element is an instance of a component (or a native html element if lowercase).

You probably want something like this:

```js
export const PrivateJailRoute = ({ Component, redirectTo, path, match, ...rest }) => {
  return <Route path={path} element={<Protected {...rest} Component={Component} />} />;
};
```

And

```js
<PrivateJailRoute
          isAuth={true}
          path="/crime"
          Component={Crime}
          time={this.state.time}
          totime={this.state.blabla}
          redirectTo="/jail"
       />
```

Comment: But element is the way it’s done in react route 6 isn’t it ?